# Example of convex function that does not have subgradient

Tags: self-learning, subgradient

Through self-study, I found out that there are some pathological functions that do not have subgradients. [https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~siva/teaching/725/lec2.pdf](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Esiva/teaching/725/lec2.pdf)

On page 2:

> Except for some very pathological functions (and only at the boundary of their domain)
> subgradients always exist

What is an example of this? And why would it not have a subgradient?

Comment: What about $-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ on $[-1, 1]$ ? Or $f(x) = 0$ for $0 \le x < 1$ and $f(1) =1$.